# AJAX Request gets cancelled with AngularJS and Spring Security

Tags: ajax, spring, angularjs, grails

We're running an external `Grails` server-application with the `Spring Security` plugin.
The front-end is running locally on `AngularJS`.

Whenever I try to login, the request is immediately canceled.. Remarkably AngularJS sends a `GET` request first with the `OPTIONS` method; this returns a `200 OK` response just fine.
The actual `POST` request does never reach the server though... what could possibly cancel my request?

The following code:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";

    $scope.loggingIn = true;

    // Setup Config
    var data = {
        j_username: $scope.user.email,
        j_password: $scope.user.password
    }
    var config = {method: 'POST', url: serverUri+'/j_spring_security_check/', data: data};

    // Dispatch HTTP Request
    $http(config)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data.status) {
            // successful login
            User.isLogged = true;
            User.username = data.username;
        }
        else {
            User.isLogged = false;
            User.username = '';
        }
        $scope.loggingIn = false;
        console.log("NOICE!");
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.loggingIn = false;
        User.isLogged = false;
        User.username = '';

        if (status == 0) {
            // Request got cancelled
            console.log("Request got cancelled.");
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

This is what the **canceled** request looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiWnb.png

This is what the `OPTIONS` request looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAj96.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `Chrome` does not handle `302 Moved temporarily` status codes efficiently when queried by AngularJS in my situation. Firefox properly shows there is a response where Chrome just shows the request as canceled with no response information whatsoever.

This question is solved, but there is still a mystery as to WHY AngularJS does not work. See my question here:
[AngularJS $http ajax does not follow Location header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267286/angularjs-http-ajax-does-not-follow-location-header)